# Jsoup returns Status=403 error after migrating the website to Amazon EC2 server

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jsoup

I recently moved my website from `HostGator` to `Amazon EC2` server due to which the android app started having connection issues. To be precise, the app fails to connect to the website URL. Android app uses `Jsoup` library to connect to URLs of the website. The crash log says:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL = "MyWebsiteURL
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:435)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
```

Please note that the website is up and working fine on the web browsers. After doing some investigation, it seems that the new server `Amazon EC2` doesn't allow requests from automated processes. `JSOUP` being a robot kind, therefore fails to get response with error 403.

Have you ever faced this problem in the past?     How do I get rid of that?

Comment: It is unclear which layer is blocking this call. Have you tried spoofing the User-Agent request header with something like `User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36` ?

Comment: @DeepakBala: I didn't spoof anything in the User-Agent. In fact, there is no change in the android app. Just migrating the server is creating this issue.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that. Perhaps an nginx or Apache rule was configured differently on the target ? If not can you try spoofing the agent ?

Comment: I can definitely try. But my concern is how does everything got changed without touching anything in the app side?

Comment: Your post does not have enough information on the web server used or the auth mechanisms you are using. So it is not possible to answer that question. The best we can do is speculate at this point. If you want to get to the bottom of the 403, update the post with how you've configured authentication for the web app.

Comment: @DeepakBala: I am finally able to diagnose the problem. I am using one plugin to block malicious requests. After disabling the plugin, everything works fine for me. The plugin blocks the request based on the content of User-Agent. I am using `userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")`. I am wondering if I am using correct content in User-Agent.

Comment: You can sniff regular HTTP traffic, copy the content of the User-Agent and get past the filter. There is no right / wrong user-agent. Glad to know you got around to solving it.